# How to remove video in apps of Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

I have created an apps to display video by Tkinter and Python. I can play, pause video in app and the problem is now I want to remove the video out of my app. I have tried a lot of solutions but It can not be removed. Code to display video in my app:

```
def load_vid(path):
    global stop
    global frame_image
    global vlabel
    video = imageio.get_reader(path)
    frame = 0
    stop = Button(tab1, text="Stop",command=stop)
    stop.place(x=350,y=370,anchor="e")
    for image in video.iter_data():
        frame += 1
        image_frame = PIL.Image.fromarray(image)
        image_frame.thumbnail((500,500))
        try:
            frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_frame)
            vlabel = Label(tab1,image=frame_image)
            #vlabel.config(image=frame_image)
            vlabel.image = frame_image
            vlabel.place(x=50, y=210, anchor="w")
            if stop == True:
                break
        except:
            sys.exit()
```

Function to remove the video:

```
def stop():
    global stop
    stop = True
    print('stop')
    vlabel.config(image = "")
```

[image]

I want to remove video out of the main frame of app.
With image, I can remove by using `.config(image ="")` but now it does not work. Is there any solution? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, you are creating a new `Label` during every frame of your video.

```
for image in video.iter_data():
    ...
    try:
        ...
        vlabel = Label(tab1,image=frame_image)
        vlabel.place(x=50, y=210, anchor="w")
        ...
    except:
        ...
```

There would be hundreds of `Label` stacking on top without knowing, and you are only setting the last created `Label` image to `None`.

Perhaps you should start by creating the `Label` outside of your loop, and only modify the image during your iteration:

```
def load_vid(path):
    ...
    stop = Button(tab1, text="Stop",command=stop)
    stop.place(x=350,y=370,anchor="e")
    vlabel = Label(tab1)
    vlabel.place(x=50, y=210, anchor="w")
    for image in video.iter_data():
        ...
        try:
            frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_frame)
            vlabel.config(image=frame_image)
            vlabel.image = frame_image
            if stop == True:
                break
        except:
            sys.exit()
```